# Is it possible to set the only first element on span in for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to set only first element on the span in for loop. Everything is working fine in the code but it's setting the last element on the span. I want to set the first element as `cust_name`.

```
success : function(data) {

                        console.log(data);

                        var jsonData = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));

                        for (var i = 0; i <= jsonData.categories.length; i++) {
                            var counter = jsonData.categories[i];

                            var cust_id     = counter.cust_id;
                            var cust_name   = counter.cust_name;
                            var cust_phone  = counter.cust_phone;

                             $('input[name="customer"]').val(cust_id);
                            $('#customernames').text(cust_name);

                            if (cust_phone=="") {

                $("#dropselect-demo1").append('<li onclick="setcustomer(\'' +cust_id+ '\',\'' +cust_name + '\',\''+cust_phone + '\')" class="list-group-item">'+cust_name+'</li>');


                            }else{
                 $("#dropselect-demo1").append('<li  onclick="setcustomer(\'' +cust_id+ '\',\'' +cust_name + '\',\''+cust_phone + '\')"  class="list-group-item">'+cust_name+' [ '+cust_phone+' ]</li>');

                            }      

                        }


                    }
```

Comment: Can you provide sample of html code which this uses. Also consider making it a runnable "script" - see editing toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
var cust_name = jsonData.categories[0].cust_name;
$('#customernames').text(cust_name);
```

As the first entry would be at `0` index in your array. Currently what happens is that it sets the text while you loop through and ends up with setting the last item in the array.

Comment: Thanks manoz for your help... is it possible to refresh this span everytime i call ajax

Comment: how do you want a refresh?

Comment: Actually this span is working on a modal. so after select once i reopen that modal it should start again...

Comment: are you using bootstrap modals?